# Getting nullpointer on a spring managed class when trying to autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am creating a spring boot application to listen from a Rabbit queue and to forward the message to a Kafka stream.
I am trying to `@Autowire` a Kafka configuring class but I am getting `NullPointerException`, more surprisingly when I list down all the spring managed beans then it gives me the object name of the class I am trying to `@Autowire`. I am not sure where I am missing.

**Starting class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.service","com.example.demo.configuration"})
public class RabbitConsumerApplication {
    
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(RabbitConsumerApplication.class, args);
        displayAllBeans();
    }
    
    public static void displayAllBeans() {
        String[] allBeanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for(String beanName : allBeanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }
    
}
```

**KafkaProducerService class:**

```
package com.example.demo.service;

@Component
public class KafkaProducerService {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<?, String> kafkaTemplate;
    
    
    public void getMessageFromMQ(Message  message) throws InterruptedException {
        
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
          configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
          configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
          configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
          DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Object, Object> defaultKafkaProducerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
          
          
        kafkaTemplate.send("testTopic",new String(message.getBody()));
        
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "KafkaProducerService [kafkaTemplate=" + kafkaTemplate + "]";
    }
    
    

}
```

**KafkaProducerConfig class:**

```
package com.example.demo.configuration;

@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
      Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
      configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
      configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
      configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
      return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
      return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

**RabbitListenerService class:**

```
package com.example.demo.service;

public class RabbitListenerService implements MessageListener{
    
    @Autowired
    private KafkaProducerService kafkaProducerService;
    
    
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("message :"+new String(message.getBody()));
        System.out.println("object:"+kafkaProducerService.toString());  //19th line. getting nullpointer on this line   
    }

}
```

**Stack trace:**

```
2021-02-20 13:55:06.750  WARN 5392 --- [tnerContainer-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1746) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1692) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1562) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1539) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1530) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1474) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:967) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1288) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1194) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.demo.service.RabbitListenerService.onMessage(RabbitListenerService.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1688) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

message :hey you
message :hey you
```

I just want to `@Autowire` KafkaProducerService class into RabbitListenerService.

Answer (score 1):

ok, i kind of solved the problem.
Even if the @autowire was happening but it was actually binding a null object because in RabbitConfig.java , i actually initialized rabbitListenerService with a new keyword and that spring IOC do not handle. I changed below way and it solved the issue.

**RabbitListenerService.java**

```
@Component
public class RabbitListenerService implements MessageListener{
    
    @Autowired
    private KafkaProducerService kafkaProducerService;
    
    
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("message :"+new String(message.getBody()));
        System.out.println("object:"+kafkaProducerService.toString());
        
        try {
            kafkaProducerService.getMessageFromMQ(message);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and then autowired this RabbitListenerService into RabbitConfig

**RabbitConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig {
    
    private static final String my_queue = "TestQueue";
    
    @Autowired
    private RabbitListenerService rabbitListenerService;
    
    
    @Bean
    MessageListenerContainer messageListnerContainer() {
        
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueues(myQueue());
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(rabbitListenerService);
        return simpleMessageListenerContainer;

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From you code it looks like you haven't defined any kafka template beans. For example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyKafkaConfig {

    ...

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        // define a template here
    }
}
```

The kafka service defined has an injected (autowired) `KafkaTemplate<?, String>`. Has such a bean been defined in a configuration class?

Please also post your stacktrace.

Comment: yes i have defined kafkaTemplate bean.. updating the question

Comment: If you take the kafka template bean out of the rabbit service and put another bean in its place, is that other bean found and not null? From the code it doesn't look like the rabbit service is managed by spring. It's not annotated with @Service.

Comment: If OP didn't defined kafkaTemplate, Spring context will fail to start

Comment: I'm sure you've already gone through all the documentation but just in case, have you looked at https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/#_register_the_listener_and_send_a_message ?

Comment: MessegaeListener implementation binds the RabbitListenerSerivice but not sure about how spring manage the object. Rabbitmq is working just fine, if you look the stacktrace, it has printed the 'hey you' message which i published to rabbit queue, even my application is publishing that hey you message to kafka stream if i manually define all the above mentioned autowired classes.. the problem is happening when i am trying to acheive that in annotation and autowire way.. need help

Comment: the reason i posted is i want to know why the way i am autowiring not working.. where i am doing wrong.. why spring has not created an object of KafkaProducerService when i am annotating it with @Component and if it is not creating any bean, then why displayAllBeans() in the starter class giving a bean of name kafkaProducerService .. need help

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, replace package with `*`, make sure it prints KafkaProducerService in bean list,

Always make practice of creating interface for impl service class

```
@Component
public class KafkaProducerServiceImpl implements KafkaProducerService
```

e.g.

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.demo.*"})
    public class RabbitConsumerApplication {
    
  ...
    }
```